# The placeholder text in my text boxes is mis aligned in chrome

Tags: css, forms, textbox, placeholder

I've got a problem in Google chrome where the placeholder text sits too high on my website
http://www.myinvestmentdecision.com.au

Click "Feedback" and you'll see the text in the placeholder sits to high. I've got a placeholder script, but it turns off when it realises that chrome has support for placeholder.

Just to proove that point here's a jsfiddle of the form itself: http://jsfiddle.net/RAANa/

Must be a CSS thing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `line-height:28px` from your css below.

```
.form input[type="text"], .form input.text, .form .calculate_box .calc {
background: transparent url(../images/input-background.png) repeat-x left top;
border: 1px solid #A1A1A1;
margin-left: -1px;
height: 28px;
line-height: 28px;
display: block;
width: 284px;
}
```

See attached screenshot with `line-height` removed
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think your line-hight:28 from here: (form.css)

```
.form { font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
.form input[type=text],
.form input.text,
.form .calculate_box .calc{
    background: transparent url(../images/input-background.png) repeat-x left top;
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    margin-left: -1px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    display: block;
    width:284px;
}
```

Is causing the problem. Remember that this declaration applies to the content of the tag, as well as the tag itself. This can get you when it comes to forms..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "right" way to do it, but adding a padding of 5px to the input field would center the placeholder for the email field.

Just add this to your CSS wherever it applies to that email field:

```
padding: 5px;
```